# How to append or alter child in a dynamic object array C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I have a dynamic array contains JSON response and i'm trying to alter or add new child but it keeps giving me this error:

> Additional information: 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'vault_data'

This is my code:

```
dynamic user = getData(apiKey); //return a dynamic JSON array .. vault_data contains a string
user.vault_data = "Trying to alter this child"; // here occur the error when I try to alter the child
user.data = "Trying to add new child"; // this will through the same error
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: It may be a key-value pair. Try: `user["vault_data"] = "Trying to alter this child";`

Comment: @JasonFaulkner Unfortunately it didn't work `Additional information: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'`, I can see the child contents like this `MessageBox.Show(user.vault_data);` that's why I'm confused why my method didn't work.

Comment: This is the drawback of using dynamic or var, the type is rather unclear. However, I see in your image that the vault_data is in some sort of `Array`. Is `user` an array?

Comment: @Ian Sorry for the late reply, yes it's an object array contains JSON response, any way around to alter or add new child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merry Christmas!

I think the best way to solve this is if you can debug on run-time just before the error happened to see what is the **type assigned** to the dynamic `user`. This info will be very useful for you to determine how to extract the data you want.

But since, at least from the image, we can see the `user` is an array, you should access it by first using the **number index** `user[46]` before you can access its members (which contains `vault_data`).

After that

1. If the member is actually a `KeyValuePair` (KVP) with `"vault_data"` being the key, you should try to give second index in key form `user[46]["vault_data"]` to access the value.
2. If it is not KVP, but a variable member, you can try to access it directly `user[46].vault_data`.
3. If it is, in fact, another array, then you may need to access the access it by second index in number form `user[46][1]` (`user[46][0]` being the `vault_data` and thus `user[46][1]` is the value you want to change).
4. And if it is a `string`, then you need to further parse `user[46]`

In all possibilities, the key is to access the member first by **indexing** the `user` array.

Comment: Thank you so much man for trying to help, and yeah it's KVP I have tried all the methods without any luck, I think it's read only, here's the class i'm using to parse json response http://stackoverflow.com/a/3806407/3785047.

Comment: I see, it is read-only. The indexing would make you able to read it but not to write anything to it, is it?

Comment: Correct, and how could I override that?

Comment: I have used the class in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8333429/3785047 and it's working perfectly so far, Thanks again for trying to help man!

Comment: Great! Glad to know that. You are welcome! Hope you can proceed well. ;)